# setTimeout in memory game

Tags: javascript

I am making a memory game in javascript that I am putting on my web page. I have 3 buttons labeled 1, 2, and 3, and they are supposed to turn green then white again in a certain order. The order is random and increases by 1 every turn. The player is then supposed to click the buttons in the correct order. The problem is that when I change the button color to green, instead of each button turning green and then white again in the correct order, the buttons turn green all at once. This is the javascript logic:

```
function lightUp() {
  var arrayOrder = gameOrder.split("");
  for(let i = 0; i < arrayOrder.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("but" + arrayOrder[i]).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("but" + arrayOrder[i]).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

`gameOrder` is a string of the number order (e.g. "12331232123")

I think the game isn't working because of the way `setTimeout` works, I believe it pauses in the background and allows the `for` loop to keep running instead of pausing the whole function for a second (which is what I am trying to do).

I want each button to turn on then off before the next button changes color. So if the order is 1 2 3, I want button 1 to turn green and then white then button 2 to turn green then white and finally for button 3 to turn green then white.

Comment: because they all run at once setting to green and they all turn off at 1000 milliseconds, they are not synchronous.

Comment: how could I fix the code so that one turns on then off and then the next and the next?

Comment: build a queue type of set up and not a loop.

Comment: you can set up a timeout with time progresively with for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As espacarello has pointed out, code you run with `setTimeout` is not synchronous. You could make the function asynchronous and await the `setTimeout`.

This is my preferred way to "animate" things with JS:

```js
async function lightUp() {
  const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  for (const i of gameOrder.split('')) {
    const el = document.getElementById(`but${i}`);
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    await sleep(1000);
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
}
```

This stays simple and elegant without messying your code with numerous callbacks, recursion, or nested `setTimeout`s.  It stays as one function.

---

**Edit:** It is important to note that IE does not support Promises or the Arrow Function syntax. See the other two answers for wider support.

Comment: And hopefully OP realizes this solution will not work on all browsers.

Comment: @epascarello Yes! Important to note. The other two answers will offer wider support at the cost of losing some conciseness. This will not work in IE at all (Arrow functions and promises **both** are not supported).

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your code is the for loop runs all at once without a delay. You code it thinking that the interval will cause the loop to wait until it is executed. Problem with that is, will just run without waiting.

Use a queue type of system where you run the step and when it is done, you run the next until you run out of things to do.

```js
var steps = [1,2,3,2,1,3,1]
var delay = 1000
var step = 0

function next () {
  var button = document.getElementById('btn' + steps[step])
  button.classList.add("on")
  window.setTimeout( function () {
    button.classList.remove("on")
    step++
    if(step<steps.length) next()
  }, delay)  
}

next()
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">One</button>
<button id="btn2">Two</button>
<button id="btn3">Three</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as below...

```js
function lightUp() {
  var arrayOrder = gameOrder.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOrder.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
       setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById("but" + arrayOrder[i]).style.backgroundColor = "green";
       }, 1000 * i - 1000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("but" + arrayOrder[i]).style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }, 1000 * i); // schedules excution increasingly for each iteration
    })(i);
  }
}
```

to learn more about how it works please refere to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58701013/6121643)

Comment: still not what OP is looking for. They will all be green.

Comment: It should be fine now :)